# How to make webpack require work like script tag

Tags: javascript, webpack, amd, commonjs

So I have some JS libs I want to use at global scope (`window`). 
They are built with webpack I assume, where their dist code has something like `module.exports=xxx`
If I put them as `<script></script>` tag in html, I can access them there.
But If I `require` them in webpack, then bundle them with webpack, I cannot see them in global scope.

Is there anything I can do to make them visible without modifying the library itself?

Comment: You don't.  You are supposed to use them using `require()`.

Comment: I'm using some language that compiles to js, and the only way to access js libs are through global namespace

Answer (score 0):

you can try [script-loader](https://github.com/webpack/script-loader),it is very simple.The code will be executed in global scope.